# Javascript - String Searching, What will fix it?

Tags: javascript

The problem is that when ever i combine two functions that:

1. gets all the id's of the HTML tags of the website
2. searches the array for "Bad Words" (AKA. "Hack","Hacker" etc...)

Code 1:

```
var eleng=document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('*').length -1;
var i=0;
var id=[];
function allids() {

    if (i < eleng) {
        id.push(document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('*')[i].id);
        if (id[i] == '' || id[i] == ' ') {
            i++;
            allids();
        } else {
            console.log(id[i]);
            i++;
            allids();
        }
    } else {
        console.log("\nDone!");
    }

}
```

Code 2:

```
var str="HELLO";
var words=['hello','hack','hacker'];
var i=0;
function check() {
    if (str.indexOf(words[i]) > -1 || str.indexOf(words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()) > -1 || str.indexOf(words[i].toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    console.log('Word Found!');
} else {
    if (i < words.length) {
        i++;
        check();
    }
   }
 }
```

Of course Code 2 would be in a new function already tried but no success :( and it would be edited to the needs of Code 1, i just couldn't be bothered re-writing the script to cater for the code. I love Save As, but let me know if it is inconvenient.

P.S I am using VANILLA Javascript, So that means no fancy stuff like Jquery!

Comment: what will be the actual value of `str`? what do you mean by combining these 2 scripts

Comment: @what is your problem? Does the array still keep the _bad words_? Are you having trouble combining the two scripts?

Comment: How come you are declaring all of these as globals? Why is var i declared globally and not scoped to a function at least? Is the intent to only be able to run the function once?

Comment: OP, you can narrow your selector by doing something like this: `var allIds = document.querySelectorAll('[id]')`. Gets all elements on page that have an attribute `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick script to enumerate all ID's on page can be found Here:
[How do I enumerate all of the html id's in a document with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115022/how-do-i-enumerate-all-of-the-html-ids-in-a-document-with-javascript)

and then we combine them into one string, and test for bad words as follows:

```js
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var allIds = [];
for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var el = allElements[i];
    if (el.id) {
        allIds.push(el.id);
    }
}
var str = allIds.join("|").toUpperCase();
var words = ['hello', 'hack', 'hacker'];
check();
function check() {
    words.forEach(function (val, id) {
        if (str.indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
            console.log('Word Found!');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="banana"></div>
<div id="sdfsdf">
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="test">
        <div id="test"></div>
        <div id="teHACKst"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="testHA"></div>
</div>
<div id="CKtest"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check index of array in javscript...

```
var array = ["rose", "violet", "blue"];

array.indexOf("blue"); // Gives 2
```

Comment: What about case sensitivity?

Comment: You can use `String.prototype.toLowerCase.call(array).split(',')` to convert to same format first.